# Why am I still getting an exception even it should be handled?

Tags: delphi, exception

Coding:

```
try
StrToInt(inputNumVariables.Text);
except
ShowMessage('Sólo números, por favor');
end;
```

Being *inputNumVariables*  a `TEdit` why would it raise and exception if I type in anything different to an integer number in the Text Edit when the try-except block should *catch* the exception, doesn't it?

Comment: This may be because you are testing inside the IDE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930102/why-is-except-not-catching-this-error

Comment: Sounds familiar. [Delphi Q&A: Why do I continue getting error messages even after I have written an exception handler?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exception-messages)

Comment: Yes, the IDE debugger catches the exception first, reports it, then the app catches it after the debugger passes it to the app. A better option is to avoid raising the exception in the first place, by using `TryStrToInt()` instead.